# Lock version of package for own npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm building a reactjs npm package so anyone can use.

This package requires of other npm dependencies like `@mui/material` at specific `5.4.0`, since newer versions requires changes on my code, that I havnen't done yet.

So on my package.json I have this:

```
...
dependencies {
  ...
  "@mui/material": "5.4.0",
  ...
}
```

**Notice that is without the `^`**

I also edited to my `yarn.lock`, to make sure it's using the same version.

---

So far so good, now the problem is that when people tries to use my package, they got it added with the `^` at the beginning.

So, my consumer package.json:

```
...
dependencies {
  ...
  "myPackage": "^1.0.0",
  ...
}
```

When I check the version installed, I found that `@mui/material` is on `5.10.x` instead of `5.4`.

How should I force a specific version, that gets installed to everyone who uses my library?

Comment: Based on what you describe, it should be `"5.4.0"`  ,  it shouldn't matter that consumers have `^1.0.0` it should not make sub modules update.  Otherwise the whole point of semantic versioning would be pointless.. :)

Comment: One note though, you can't force your users to use `5.4.0`, if they have other packages that also rely on `@mui/material ^5.x.x`, you will end up with 2 installs (instances) of it, and that can often cause issues.

Comment: Your understanding of semver and `^` is incorrect. You should be listing your `mui` dependency as [`peerDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) anyway. That indicates to your package consumers what they should be using.